# Run any other javascript after the Display Templates have rendered the content

Tags: 2013

This is the issue:

1. I create a ContentBySearchWebpart, specified with my custom Display
   templates.'
2. I want to run some other javascript code, after the Display
       Templates have rendered the content
3. I then register my custom javascript file in Display template.

   ```
           $includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Slider.js")'
   ```

   The problem is that my Slider.js file code **executes** *before* the 'Display
       Templates' Javascript code does.

Can anybody provide me a way to execute my Slider.js code *after* the
    display templates have rendered the content of
    ContentBySearchWebpart(CSWP)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

:) my issue is solved.

I did following:

1. Registered the custom JS file in Control_YourTemplateName.html
   file(like Control_Banner).

   `$includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/HWScripts/Banner.js");`
2. Added these three lines under the first div after body tag, in
   YourTemplateName.html (like Banner.html) file.

   ```
    <!--#_  
    ctx.OnPostRender = [];
    ctx.OnPostRender.push(function(){ 
       CustomMethodWhichIsIncludedInTheCustomJSFile();
    });
    _#-->
   ```

**But a better solution is provided below:**

You can skip defining `OnPostRender` yourself. CBS Display Templates have this function baked in:

```
<!--#_
   AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){
       alert(ctx.Title + "finished rendering!");
   });
_#-->
```

There is also `AddPreRenderCallback(ctx, function(){});`

Comment: Yes it is better :)

Comment: Is there a way to add the post render function from outside the template? For example I have a code snippet on the page and I want it to call some javascript after the cswp renders?

Answer (score 0):

You can add line of code after  including script,

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded( function() { <your custom function name>; }, 'name of   display template ');
```

for example:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded( function() { console.dir( SP.Res ); }, 'sp.js');
```

Comment: This is not what i am asking