# Run javascript after display template loaded

Tags: 2013, javascript, display-template

How can I run some JavaScript after my display template has loaded. I have tried:

```
AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function () {     
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        alert(jQuery('.ms-srch-hover-subTitle').text());      
    });
})
```

but that doesn't work. `.ms-srch-hover-subTitle` is getting added from the display template. so I want the display template to be put on screen and then for the js to run

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by that didn't worked?

Comment: ran before display template was loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are registering on load event. Instead modify as follows

```
AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function () {     
    alert(jQuery('.ms-srch-hover-subTitle').text());      
})
```

Also take a look at this [Run any other javascript after the Display Templates have rendered the content](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49349/run-any-other-javascript-after-the-display-templates-have-rendered-the-content)

Comment: that has the same result

Comment: can you please explain what `.ms-srch-hover-subTitle` this control does. Is it getting populated from the display template?

Comment: yes it's getting populated from the display template

Comment: Can you please add more code.

Comment: @Dillydallydave I have added a link. Also check that and make sure you are following the correct way.

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint does provide a few options.

1) Script on Demand: (load a js file then execute my code.)

function stuffThatRequiresSP_JS(){
    //your code
}
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js")

2) Delay until loaded (wait for a js file, then run)

function stuffToRunAfterSP_JS(){
    //your code
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(stuffToRunAfterSP_JS, "sp.js")

3) load after other stuff finishes

function runAfterEverythingElse(){
    // your code
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");

Sources:

executeFunc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936250/sharepoint-2013-add-javascript-after-whole-page-load).

Comment: Please read question carefully. Its not about page load.