# Unable to get property 'PageManager' of undefined or null reference SP2013

Tags: list, custom-list, script

I've just created a new custom list on my site, with a simple list, one text column, no javascript, no CEWP, just a very basic vanilla function.

Running the page with PF12 open, the error "Unable to get property 'PageManager' of undefined or null reference" comes up.

Is this normal? What is causing this? Any fix?

Comment: did you check in different browsers?

Comment: I only have access to the one Browser IE 11, but I did try the different compatibility options within PF12, and all came up with the same issue

Comment: Just as a test I created a new Page on the site, and when running P12 I get the error "Unable to get property 'Resources' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: What about the list functionality? can you add items and other operations?

Comment: When I add an item I get a failure on window.document.execCommand("EnableInlineTableEditing",false,false). On save I get 'WPSCinpreview' is undefined, then Unable to get property 'MenuTitle' of undefined or null reference.. keep pressing go, then the list is displayed complete with the item saved.

Comment: On view item I get 'WPSCinpreview' is undefined

Comment: are you using sharepoint online? not easy to diagnose, if possible could you try creating a new site?

Comment: Yes, using SP Online, and I've tried another site as well... same issues.

Comment: lets wait for more answers but i think you should raise a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: I've checked other non SharePoint websites and other people computers... it seems to be limited to my profile.
It appears to relate to "break on throw" set for exceptions in JavaScript ref:http://forums.asp.net/t/1919704.aspx?JavaScript+runtime+error+0x800a139e+SyntaxError
Can't find the solution yet. How do I set this option off?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging causes these errors to throw. Do   E in PF12 and select the "Never break on Exceptions" option.

Problem goes away!