# How to call a JavaScript inline of Item display template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2016, display-template, content-search-web-part

I am editing an Item Display Template (for a content search web part) on SP2016 enterprise.

In the display template (Item_LargePicture.html), I inserted a JavaScript function to randomly return a image tag (e.g. `<img src="/sites/os/PublishingImages/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="">` ). The function named `getImageTag()`.

In the main html part of template I call my JS function like below syntax:

```
    <span style="display: table-cell;width: 50%">
<article id="_#= containerId =#_" data-displaytemplate="ItemLargePicture"> 

            <a class="image fit thumb" href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1) =#_" id="_#= pictureLinkId =#_">
                
                <!--#_
                     document.write(getImageTag());
                 _#-->

            </a>
            <span class="text-block" id="_#= dataContainerId =#_">
                <a href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1) =#_" id="_#= line1LinkId =#_">
                    <h3 id="_#= line1Id =#_"> _#= line1 =#_</h3>
                </a>
            </span>
</article></span>
```

When I load the SharePoint page with display template, all I got is `Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in either the Web Part properties or Result Types.`

I cannot debug with above error. Could you advise the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
getImageTag() {
    ...

    jQuery('a.thumb').append('<img src="/sites/os/PublishingImages/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="">');
}

AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function () {     
    getImageTag(); 
})
```

You can adjust the jQuery selector for parent `a` element as per your requirements.

OR

```
getImageTag() {
    ...

    return '<img src="/sites/os/PublishingImages/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="">';
}

<!--#_
   AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){
       alert(ctx.Title + "finished rendering!");
   });
_#-->
```

**References**:

1. [Run javascript after display template loaded](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125967/run-javascript-after-display-template-loaded)
2. [Run any other javascript after the Display Templates have rendered the content](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49349/run-any-other-javascript-after-the-display-templates-have-rendered-the-content)

Comment: Hi @Mark L, did you try this? Is it working for you?